# How to maintain state of search portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have 'Search' portlet in page 1 and 'Setup Data' portlet in page 2.
I do a search in page 1 and the search results are displayed. Now I navigate to page 2 by using the navigation menu of native Liferay and do some operations there. **When I come back to my search portlet, the search results are not retained, as page will be refreshed and then portlet also will refresh its content. But I want to pertain state of portlet like it should pertain the search operation what I did and results as well.**

Please provide suggestions on how to do this. **And I got there is configuration in IBM portal like do we have any configuration in Liferay.**

Answer (score 0):

Check the parameter `layout.default.p_l_reset` in [portal.properties](http://docs.liferay.com/ce/portal/6.2/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html). Be aware that this results in higher memory consumption as state is maintained. But that's what you ask for.

Comment: Thanks and won't it refresh the content of the portlet on next page navigation.

Comment: Well, try it. I wouldn't expect it, as you specifically would have prohibited a state reset with this flag. It's not "on first page navigation keep the state", but it's "on - any - page navigation keep the state"